# The problem I have is I do not know how to move my Sprite with the assigned keybinds?

Tags: python, pygame

I want to have my character move left and right at the click of the keybinds, but I don't know how to, I've realised I need to assign them to the character variable to do this. However I don't know how to go about this.

I have already asked this before but the solution did was difficult to follow compared to my code so I couldn't find a solution.

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

window = pygame.display.set_mode((750, 750))

pygame.display.set_caption("PeaShooters")

avatar = pygame.image.load('Sprite 1 Red.png')
background = pygame.image.load('Bg.jpg')

x = 64
y =64
width = 40
height = 60
vel = 5
white = (255, 255, 255)

def drawGrid():
    window.blit(background, (0,0))
    window.blit(avatar, (300,500))
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [50, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,50], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [600,600], [600, 50], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,600], [600, 600], 5)
    pygame.draw.line(window, white, [50,450], [600, 450], 5)
    pygame.display.update()

running = True
while running:
    pygame.time.delay(100) 

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > 455:
        y += vel

    if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 55:
        x -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 565:
        y -= vel

    if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 575 :
        x += vel

    x += x

    drawGrid()

pygame.quit()
```

I expect the sprite to move in a designated direction when clicking a certain button this does not happen.

Comment: you have `(x, y)` so use it `window.blit(avatar, (x,y))`

Comment: So what's happening? Is your character frozen?

Comment: Yes, I don't know how to move it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove this useless line

```
x += x
```

And use `(x, y)` to set avatar in correct position

```
window.blit(avatar, (x, y))
```

This works for me.

---

**EDIT:** you have some mistake in `y -= ...` and `y += ...` - you have to change places.

And `y > 55` instead of `y > 455`

```
if keys[pygame.K_w] and y > 55:
    y -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_s] and y < 565:
    y += vel

if keys[pygame.K_a] and x > 55:
    x -= vel
if keys[pygame.K_d] and x < 575 :
    x += vel
```

Comment: Would you be able to say what the mistake could be? Thank you.

Comment: you have to put `y -= ` in place of `y +=` and `y +=` in place of `y -=` . I think there is too big value in `y > 455` - it should be rather something smaller - ie. `y > 55`

Comment: did you remove `x += x` ? When I remove it and use `window.blit(avatar, (x, y))` then I can move left, right, top. To move down I needed to change `y +=`

Comment: Where have you put window.blit(avatar, (x, y))?

Comment: you have to only replace `(300, 500)` with `(x, y)`  and keep it in the same place